# gradle task to zip multiple directories independently

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create a task that looks inside a folder and zips all the folders within that folder to some output folder.

**Initial state:**

```
Folder1
    -> project1
        ->code //some more files within project1
    -> project2
        ->code
```

**Target state:**

```
Destination
    project1.zip
    project2.zip
```

I tried using the below code, but it is zipping all the content within the folder1

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
   from 'Folder1'   
   archiveName 'Compress.zip'
   destinationDir file('build')
}
```

I probably might need to use some collections which contains the project1 and project2 info and iteratively zip to the destination folder. Having issues with this approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each Gradle `Zip` task can only create a single Zip file, as you can read [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/create-zip-files-in-a-loop/6205/2).

So, you need to create multiple tasks. Therefore, you can iterate over the subdirectories and create a new `Zip` task for each one of them. The generated tasks can be bundled in a root task via `dependsOn`:

```
task myZip() {
    file('Folder1').eachDir { sub ->
        dependsOn tasks.create("${name}_${sub.name}", Zip) {
            from sub
            baseName sub.name
            destinationDir file('Destination')
        }
    }
}
```