# How do I exclude all subdirectories from Gradle zip task using Ant include/exclude pattern?

Tags: gradle, ant

I want to create a task that will zip up all the files in a directory, ignoring all subdirectories. At the same time, I want to iterate through all the subdirectories and create zips that include the files in those directories (and ignoring any further subdirectories).

Thus, for this directory structure, I want the following zips:

```
$ls build/dirA
fileA
dirB

$ls build/dirA/dirB
fileB

I should get zip/zipA containing fileA, zip/zipB containing fileB.
```

I am using code based on the answer here: [gradle task to zip multiple directories independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551572/gradle-task-to-zip-multiple-directories-independently/43552558)  Essentially, I create a zip task for each zip artifact to be created, with a dependency on the top level task.

```
task myZip() {
    file('build').eachDir { dir ->
        dir.eachDir { sub ->
            dependsOn tasks.create("zip$sub.name", Zip) {
                from sub
                baseName sub.name
                destinationDir file('zip')
            }
        }

        dependsOn tasks.create("zip$dir.name", Zip) {
            from dir
            baseName dir.name
            excludes ['*/**']
            destinationDir file('zip')
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be in the exclude pattern.  I get the correct zips for the sub directories, but the parent directory includes `fileA` and `dirB/fileB`.

What is the correct way to do this please?

*Note I have not put an exclude for the iteration through the subdirectories, as I figure this pattern needs to be the same as for the parent directory, which I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below script, it would resolve your issue:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES
task myZip {
    file('folder').traverse(type: DIRECTORIES) {
        def path = it.path
        def zipFile = it.name + '.zip'
        ant.zip(destfile: zipFile){
          fileset(dir: path) {
            include (name: "*")
            type (type: "file")
          }
        }
    }

    doLast {
      copy {
        from "."
        include "*.zip"
        into file("zip")
      }
    }
}
```

Here is some example test:

```
$ tree folder
folder
└── dirA
    ├── dirB
    │   ├── dirC
    │   │   ├── dirD
    │   │   └── fileC
    │   └── fileB
    └── fileA

4 directories, 3 files
```

And it generate the three zip files into zip folder as well as root folder.

```
$ ls -1 zip/
dirA.zip
dirB.zip
dirC.zip
```